# Who was piloting the White Knight Infinite Stratos?

Tags: infinite-stratos

As the question states, is it ever revealed who the pilot was? Since Byakushiki contains Core number 001 which is the same one that powered the white knight, can we assume that the pilot was Shinonono Tabane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

> The White Knight's pilot was Chifuyu Orimura, as confirmed in the light novels, and heavily implied during the anime.

Source: http://infinite-stratos.wikia.com/wiki/White_Knight